# Bypass the chrome XSS Auditor by changing attributes in forms

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, xss

Recently Ive read a post - [Web Application Design Does Matter - Google Chrome XSS Auditor Bypass : Version <= 32.0.1700.41 m Aura !](http://zeroknock.blogspot.sg/search/label/Bypassing%20XSS%20Auditor)

It introduces a way to bypass [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome)'s xss auditor.

In the post it says:

> ...let's analyze a bypass in latest (and earlier) versions of Google
>   Chrome browser. The web page URL looks like as follows:
>   **http://www.example.com/index.php?m=login** which generates the form as follows:  [image: console image from blog] For Injection, we crafted
>   the URL as follows:
>
> **http://www.example.com/index.php/" onmouseover="JavaScript:alert(document.location)" name="?m=login .**
>
> In this injection, we have not injected in "m" parameter rather we
>   have played with the URI structure. The idea is to tweak the form
>   layout rather the value accepted by the "m" parameter. If you place
>   your injection in "m" parameter, it gets nullified by the XSS Auditor.
>   Let's see how the injection occurs: As a result, Google Chrome XSS
>   auditor is bypassed.** [image: XSS example from blog] 
>   [image: alert example from blog]

My question is **how can it change the form by using the uri only?** Ive tried this but it does not work.

Is it something related to the "m" parameter? and since the code does not deal with the `$_GET[]` , so I don't see any method to embed the js code into the form tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because often something like

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="POST">
```

is used to make the form POST to the same page it is rendered to. The issue here is that someone can manipulate the URL itself, not just the query string. So in this case the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is rendered unescaped and thus prone to XSS.